# Are there any standard library analogues:

Tags: haskell

While coding some algorithm problems, I've used these functions, and I wonder if there are any standard library analogues implementing their functionality:

Maps a list of functions to one value:

```
mapX :: a -> [a -> b] -> [b]
mapX _ [] = []
mapX x (f:fs) = [f x] ++ (mapX x fs)
```

Maps a binary function to two lists:

```
map2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
map2 _ [] [] = []
map2 f (ax:axs) (bx:bxs) = [f ax bx] ++ map2 f axs bxs
```

To me, it's kinda weird that `all [] == True` :(

```
all' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all' _ [] = False
all' f l  = all f l
```

Does the `^` operator implement fast exponentiation?

```
fastPow :: Int -> Int -> Int
fastPow x 0 = 1
fastPow x a
    | even a     = exp2 * exp2
    | odd a      = exp2 * exp2 * x
    where
        exp2 = fastPow x (div a 2)
```

Comment: Consider the expression `all f xs && all f ys`. Would you expect this to be equivalent to `all f (xs ++ ys)`? This requires `all _ [] = True`. The more general concept (and intuitive justification) is that `True` is the identity for `(&&)`. This is the same reason an empty product is 1 (e.g., 0!, x^0) and an empty sum is 0 (e.g., x * 0).

Comment: thx, now I see there's a point :)

Comment: Consider `all [] == True` in another language; you may implement it as `for item in list { if !item: return false }; return true`

Comment: The Haskell Prelude (^) does the exponentiation with fewer multiplications than yours (on average).  Just count how many you need for, e.g., an exponent of 8.  (^) uses 3 multiplications.

Comment: Besides what camccann said, which is totally right, were you using `all` in a particular context, where `all'` felt more appropriate? Or just explore the libraries, and you thought it was kind of weird?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Maps a list of functions to one value:**

```
map ($x) fs
```

`$` is the function application operator, so `($x)` is a function that applies its argument to `x`.

**Maps a binary function to two lists:**

`zipWith`. You can find this even if you don't know the function name by searching for the type signature on [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

**Does ^ operator implement fast exponentiation?**

[Yes](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Real.html#%5E).